# A problem in l led or arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano

When I am working on arduino nano and i uploaded a file that will blink led at 13th pin but rather than at 13th pin l-led is blinking. I even tried resetting it and uploading an empty file and again uploading the 13th pin blinking code but still l-led is blinking. What is the problem?

Comment: 13th pin is pin12 ... the numbering starts at zero ... the LED is on the 14th pin

Answer (score 0):

The `L` LED and pin 13 are one and the same thing. That LED is connected directly to pin 13. If you blink pin 13 then that LED will blink.

Comment: but the problem is the led that i connected to 13th pin is also not glowing

Comment: Did you connect it the right way around? Did you include the required resistor?

Comment: yeah i did that and now even the blank code is not uploading